# Unable to get code paramteter in redirect uri for instagram

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, instagram, instagram-api, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to integrate instagram in my web. I registered my app for sandbox mode. I have got the client_id and client_secret. I have also registered my redirect_uri.

I am following below link from instagram to get access_token

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

My registered website is https://goo.gl/C0q97F which is url shortner of my localhost
And Redirect URI is https://goo.gl/UMLSaV

Now I make call to get the code and the call looks like:
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://goo.gl/UMLSaV&scope=basic&response_type=code

After this i am able to debug into my redirect uri method as I am using Spring mvc but i am not getting any code parameter in request object. Actually my request object have empty parameterMap.

I am quite surprised as instagram succesfully redirecting call after authorizing my app from user but not sending any code parameter in query string as i need this code to get **access_token**.

It would be great if someone can tell me that what mistakes am i doing in this process?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your new client id in Instagram.

http://instagram.com/developer/

After registration you will get a client Id use this for request.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkuJtIcXR68